# PostgreSQL, two queries in one string

Tags: postgresql

By using libpq I have to open new database and set a comment on it.
For now I do this with two queries:

> "CREATE DATABASE dbname ENCODING = 'UTF8'"

and

> "COMMENT ON DATABASE dbname IS 'mycomment'"

Can this two queries be written and send to PQExec in one string?
How this string should look like?

Comment: No. Unfortunately, there is no comment option for create darabase command (I think there should be too)

Comment: Of course it is comment option, I uses it for a long time.

Comment: Not according to the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two specific queries cannot, because CREATE DATABASE is special.

Other queries can, simply by separating them with semicolons.